# How to display data in ListView Control of asp.net with group title?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Suppose i have user table with userid username and city, i want to display all user group by city title and under that respective user. is this possible using listview ?

```html
<br/>
City1<br/>
Userinfo<br/>
Userinfo<br/>
Userinfo
<br/>
City2<br/>
Userinfo
<br/>
City3<br/>
Userinfo<br/>
Userinfo
<br/>
```

Comment: Could you give some more info?

Comment: A list which display usernames(Item) which is divided by their city name(Group title)... and what can i do i have image what i want but don't have that much reputation to upload it.

ex.

City1
-User1
-User2 \n
City2
-User3 \n
City3
-User5
-User6
-User7 \n

list like that...

Comment: You want only show? Or it need to be editable/clickable in some way?

Comment: editable but I am not even able to show so editing is later perspective. And the main problem is no of item variance into group so how can we handle that If the no of item is different all the time.